# How to remove "small" patterns inside "global" pattern using sed

Tags: sed

Here is the example of html file:

```
cat tmp.html
<table><td>123</td>1<td>456</td>2<td>789</td></table>
```

final result that I'm trying to achieve should look like this:

```
<table><td>123</td><td>456</td><td>789</td></table>
```

sed removes some extra data if I'm using this command:

```
$ sed 's/\/td>.*<td/\/td><td/g' tmp.html
<table><td>123</td><td>789</td></table>
```

is there a way to remove data between tags using sed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{gsub(/<\/td>[^<]*/,"</td>")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** `sed` solution.

```
sed 's@</td>[^<]*@</td>@g'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sed treats `*` as greedy i.e. it matches as much text as possible. So in this case, the `.*` matched and consumed everything starting from the first `/td>` up until the last `<td`. There is no way to make it reluctant in sed but you can restrict what the `*` matches - instead of using `.`, specifically match everything that's not `<`.

`sed 's/\/td>[^<]*<td/\/td><td/g' tmp.html`

But this will become problematic if you can have other HTML tags outside the `<td>`. You will have to use lookaheads which sed does not support.

Also, you can avoid escaping slash and uncomplicate the expression if you use a different delimiter for sed:

`sed 's#/td>[^<]*<td#/td><td#g' tmp.html`

Comment: Your answer directly provides the final working command with no explanation, or what's wrong with OPs command. I've first corrected OP's own command to make it work, providing explanation as to why. Then I've added an optional change (delimiter) to make it better. Pretty much only the last line of my answer is similar to yours. The fact that OP accepted your answer means they're happy with just the working command. But I think mine should exist for others looking for the rationale behind it.